# how to find B matrix if AB is zero matrix

Tags: matrices

**How can i find (2 x 3) B matrix if AB is zero matrix and A(2 x 2 )= -1  -1( 1st row) 3  3 ( 2nd row)**

**I do not know how to find it**

Comment: If $B_1$ and $B_2$ are the rows of $B$, then the rows of the product $AB$ are $a_{11}B_1+a_{12}B_2$ and $a_{21}B_1+a_{22}B_2$, respectively. What does that tell you about the rows of $B$?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Each column of $B$ is in the null space of $A$.